# Was death addressed in "Childhood's End'?

Tags: arthur-c-clarke, childhoods-end

What happened to humans that died in *Childhood's End*, either before the arrival of the Overlords or after? Did death allow you to join the Overmind?

Answer (score 7):

It's been some years since I read the book, but as I remember it, only the chidren were part of the overmind. Old style humans weren't.
And if dying allowed old style humans to join the overmind, there wouldn't have been the reaction described in the book - which seems based on a permanent separation. If it was just temporary, it would be unlikely to to create the reaction described.

Comment: This is my recollection as well. Humans born before the arrival of the Overlords, and many born after, live and die as normal. Some decades after the initial arrival of the Overlords a generation of children is born who are fundamentally different from their parents generation and are psychically joined in a group mind. Ultimately this group mind will join the "Overmind" and ascend to a non-material existence, all other humans die either naturally or commit suicide.